# Ember.js "isDirty" not being cleared on save with both Epf and Ember-Data (1.0.0.beta.2)

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, epf

I'm having a problem using Ember.  When I change a model, its "isDirty" flag becomes true, which is what I expect.

However, after that its "isDirty" flag is true, even after I save that model.

Here's a minimal Rails + Ember project (so I can actually save the model) that shows the situation:

https://github.com/csterritt/etst

Am I doing something wrong?  Is this expected behavior?

Thanks!

---

**Edit:** Turns out that, as Jeremy Green pointed out below, the "isDirty" flag works for Ember Data.

And, it works with the current Ember 1.0.0 (standard, not -latest) and Ember Data beta.

I was doing:

```
  isClean: ( ->
    ! @get("isDirty")
  ).property("name", "age", "favorite_food")
```

Which was due to a misunderstanding on my part.  Changing this to:

```
  isClean: ( ->
    ! @get("isDirty")
  ).property("isDirty")
```

Works properly.

Unfortunately, this doesn't solve the Epf version's problem.  Epf-ites?

Answer (score 0):

Can you post a JSBin demonstrating the issue?  Here's a simple JSBin with the `FixtureAdapter` that shows the `isDirty` flag being cleared correctly.

http://jsbin.com/ucanam/1058/edit

I also just double checked in one of my apps that's using the `RESTAdapter` against a real API, and it is also clearing the flag.

[EDIT] : The JSBin that I posted is running ember-data-latest, and my real app is using beta 2.

Answer (score 0):

With regards to EPF, `isDirty` is currently a volatile computed property. I will change this soon.